# Copying data from one cell in another based on date

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet, using google sheets, that I have formed into the following metrics:

Column A is the dates of the month
Column B is the data

I want to be able to copy the data from Column B into Column D Cell 1 based on today's date and have Column D Cell 1 update every day based on the day of the month it is.

Example:
Today's date 6/6/2018

Data is pulled from Column B using the defined date of today, and posted into D:1, and each new day the column is automatically updated.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
=VLOOKUP(DAY(TODAY()), A:B, 2, True)
```

`VLOOKUP` args:

- arg1: item to match
- arg2: data-range
- arg3: data to be picked from nth column of matching row
- arg4: is_sorted

more [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) such as this:

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),A2:B32,2)
```

This will look in column A from cell 2-32 for [today](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en)'s date and get the value from column B in the same row. Note that you might want to modify the spreadsheet settings calculation as it by default only calculates today on change.

Answer (score 0):

**`=QUERY( A1:B6; "select B where A =date """&TEXT(TODAY();"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" "; 0)`**

[image]
[image]